# Combining multiple dice event probabilities obtained from binomial distribution

Tags: probability, dice

From [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654073/probabilities-for-rolling-multiple-dice-and-getting-one-number-or-greater/1654107), I've obtained the formula for binomial distribution

$$
\binom n kp^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$

and used it to obtain probabilities of a *hit*, where a hit is a die roll at *X* or lower, with probability $p$ derived from *X*.

For example, rolling 3 dice ($k$) hitting on a 2 or lower ($p$ = $\frac{2}6$), the probability of getting 1 hit ($n$) *exactly* is 44.44%, or if I want *at least* 1 hit it's 70.37% by adding all probabilities from $\sum_{n=1}^k$

6 ($k$) dice at 1 ($p$ = $\frac{1}6$), hoping for *at least* 1 hit have the probability of 66.51%

These are two separate dice rolls, one with 3@2, another with 6@1, each having independent probabilities for "at least" 1 hit, or "at least" 2 hits, etc.

How do I sum up these two separate probabilities? I would like to know, after rolling 3@2 and 6@1, what is the probability of getting *at least* 1 hit, and also *exactly* 1 hit.

Thank you for your time.

*Edit 09/09/2016*

I have found a near answer to what I was asking [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675895/dice-rolling-at-least-k-on-n-six-sided-dice-with-a-twist/678182#678182), but I'm still looking for a way to simplify the formula, or get an answer without having to iterate so much.

For example, we'll have 3 dice hitting on 1 and 2 dice hitting on a 2 or lower. We are looking for the probability of at least one hit (and the max is 5, because we have 5 dice)

*k* = hits

*y* = 3 dice @ 1

*z* = 2 dice @ 2

$P(k) = \binom n kp^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

The formula ends up being

$P_y(\ge1) = P_y(1) + P_y(2) + P_y(3)$

$P_z(\ge1) = P_z(1) + P_z(2)$

$P_{y+z}(2) = P_y(1) * P_z(1)$

$P_{y+z}(3) = (P_y(2) * P_z(1)) + (P_y(1) * P_z(2))$

$P_{y+z}(4) = (P_y(3) * P_z(1)) + (P_y(2) * P_z(2))$

$P_{y+z}(5) = P_y(3) * P_z(2)$

$$P_{y+z}(\ge1) = P_y(\ge1) + P_z(\ge1) + P_{y+z}(2) + P_{y+z}(3) + P_{y+z}(4) +P_{y+z}(5) = 74.28\%$$

This works, but it includes a lot of iteration. I'm wondering if there is some way to simplify the formula, so that fewer calculations need to be made.

Comment: What do you know about combining probabilities of two different events (i.e. union and intersection)? There are some formulae that would be worth starting with.

Comment: It’s much simpler to compute the probability of at least one hit by computing the probability of *no* hits and subtracting that from $1$.

Comment: I am not familiar with union or intersection in terms of statistics (though I am in terms of databases).

Also, I would ultimately want the probably of X hits, not just 1. I can currently do that thanks to your answer in the other question @amd